# I want to enable deployment only from the branch names(starting with hotfix and master). How can I do that?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am writing a `Jenkinsfile` and trying to enable deployment from the branch names(starting with `master` and `hotfix`). How can I do that? Below is my groovy code. This works if I specify only one branch. How can I do that for multiple branches?

```
// Create and Deploy to STAGE Environment
            stage ('Create and Deploy to k8s stage Environment') {
                when {
                    allOf {
                        expression {
                            branch_name.startsWith('master')
                        }
                    }
                }
                options {
                    skipDefaultCheckout()
                }
                steps {
                    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "$env.K8S_STAGE_NS_TOKEN" , variable: 'STAGE_TOKEN')]) {
                        kubernetesDeploy(hcEnv: 'stage', hcToken: "${STAGE_TOKEN}")
                    }
                }
            }
```

The below code doesn't work if I specify 2 branch names but the above one works.

```
// Create and Deploy to PROD Environment
            stage ('Create and Deploy to k8s production Environment') {
                when {
                    allOf {
                        expression {
                            branch_name.startsWith('hotfix')
                            branch_name.startsWith('master')
                        }
                    }
                }
                options {
                    skipDefaultCheckout()
                }
                steps {
                    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "$env.K8S_PROD_NS_TOKEN" , variable: 'PROD_TOKEN')]) {
                        kubernetesDeploy(hcEnv: 'prod', hcToken: "${PROD_TOKEN}")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to specify multiple branches for the pipeline, or how to execute stages mapped to different branches, or something else entirely?

Comment: how to execute stages mapped to different branches? I have updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
expression { return (env.GIT_BRANCH.startsWith('origin/master') || env.GIT_BRANCH.startsWith('hotfix'))}
```

OR

you can also try this

```
 expression { return (env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith('origin/master') || env.GIT_BRANCH.startsWith('origin/hotfix'))}
```

1. I am not sure if your branch name starts with origin or without origin so use it according to you. I would suggest instead of `startsWith` use `contains`.
2. Also instead of `allOf` i guess you need `anyOf` because you want to run stage for either if it's master branch or hotfix branch and both at the same time can't be true so

Comment: I had tried using `OR` operator but making some minor mistake. Thank you very much for your time. It worked.